# Improve performance of ng-repeat with 1600 items. Causing page load delay and performance issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a UI layout with perfect-scrollbar to render a list of items. There are 1600 items which I need to display (without limiting the number of items displayed with any pagination) within the scrollable section so that user can scroll all the items at once (this is a requirement for me and I have less control over this).

The angular template rendering this view is below:

```
<my-scrollable-section>
    <div 
        ng-class="myCtrl.itemId == item.itemId ? 'item-active-background' : ''"
        ng-click="myCtrl.itemClickHandler(item)"
        ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.items | filter:myCtrl.search track by item.itemId">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ::item.models">
                <span>{{::value}}</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ::item.frameworks">
                <span>{{::value}}</span>
            </div>
    </div>
</my-scrollable-section>
```

The filter in this repeat is linked to a search bar just above this view to narrow down the items being displayed.

The problem now is:

1. The page does not load instantaneously and freezes for 5-8 seconds. The number of watchers is not the cause for this, as I tried one-time bindings to bring the watcher count below 1500.
2. Once the page has loaded, the scroll is very slow and does not seem user-friendly at all.
3. I tried suggesting a pagination to limit the number of items being rendered at a time, but as mentioned earlier, I have little control over the requirements and it's required that all items be present on the scrollable list.

Can these load and performance issues be fixed with angular? Please do not suggest infinite-scroll as even if we use an infinite scroll, in the end, once all items are on the page, the UI will again become slow.

Comment: So you need virtual scroll. Take any implementation you like.

Comment: If I opt virtual scroll, it would interfere with perfect-scroll that I already am using for scroll. Also, would that limit the items somehow so that page load is a bit faster?

Comment: you can use limitTo and add search functionality in your ng-repeat if you want.

Comment: Point no 3 "I tried suggesting a pagination to limit the number of items being rendered at a time, but as mentioned earlier, I have little control over the requirements and its required that all items be present on the scrollable list.".

Comment: Try lazy loading on scroll? Let's say it's possible to fit 10 items in the viewport, then load initially 20 items. On scroll start loading the next 20 items.

Comment: I advice you to read about how virtual scrolling works, cause this is the only solution. If perfect-scrollbar doesnt support it - you must customize it or use something else. And there is never other solution.

Comment: @Inder have you found exact root cause for performance degradation? I've just tried to create 16 000 random items with vanilla js and it took 93ms to create them and slightly more to render(so Performance audit displays 90% of time were required to render that - so it took just ~1s in total)

Answer (score 2):

// Try with, on scroll call function & update renderLimit value.

check example here - [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/IG0LibJxoq3oGe5MLrLN)

```
// set initial limit to say 30.
$scope.renderLimit = 30;
// bind this function with directive.
$scope.updateLimit = function(value){
  if(value == 'bottom'){
    $scope.contValue += 1;
    $scope.renderLimit += 30;
  }
};

// directive will be
// custome directive for scrollHandler
app.directive('scrollHandler', function(){
  return{
      scope: { 
             scrollHandler: '&',
             dataChange:'='
         },
      link:function(scope,element){

          scope.$watch(function(){return scope.dataChange;},function(){
              if(element[0].scrollTop > (element[0].scrollHeight - element[0].clientHeight - 50))
                element[0].scrollTop=(element[0].scrollHeight - element[0].clientHeight - 50);
          });
          element.bind('scroll',function(){
              var scrPosition = element[0].scrollTop;

              if(scrPosition === 0)
                 scrPosition = "top";
              else if(scrPosition === (element[0].scrollHeight - element[0].clientHeight))
                 scrPosition = "bottom";
              scope.$apply(function() {
                 scope.scrollHandler()(scrPosition);
               });
          });

      },
      restrict:"A"
  };
});
```

HTML::

```
<div scroll-handler="myCtrl.updateLimit" data-change="contValue">
    <div 
            ng-class="myCtrl.itemId == item.itemId ? 'item-active-background' : ''"
            ng-click="myCtrl.itemClickHandler(item)"
            ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.items| limitTo:renderLimit | filter:myCtrl.search track by item.itemId">
      // item contents...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any references or examples on how to use `onScrollHandler` function?

Comment: For this, perfect scrollbar events need to be handled in angular. Any pointers how to do this ?

Comment: onScrollHandler can be handle by various way, one of them i used directive. please check plunker demo.

Comment: Couple of issues with this approach:  1. Instead of $scope.initialLimit += 30; , it should be $scope.renderLimit += 30; as initialLimit is not being used anywhere in template. 2. On scrolling to the end continously, I come back to the same problem (huge list of items in ng-repeat which makes the DOM slow). Any updates to this approach will be highly appreciated as this approach comes very close to what I want to achieve. Just that we need to keep reducing the items from the top of list as well on scrolling to bottom to keep rendered list small.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [vs-repeat](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat)?

I've been using this api to handle large number of items to be repeated. And i haven't encountered any problems.

Just a simple:

`<div vs-repeat>
    <div ng-repeat="item in someArray">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>`

would solve your problem.

Comment: Can I use vs-repeat inside a perfect-scrollbar section ?

Comment: I tried the vs-scroll but it did not work inside of a perfectscrollbar section. Do you have a working example or a fiddle that can help in this case?